# Orchestrate.js triggers both 'promise.fail' and 'promise.then'

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Orchestrate has a client for NodeJS. It is based on promises so I should define a function then and a function fail. The first should be triggered when the request is successful and the second one when it fails. But sometimes it triggers both and I don't understand why.

Here is an example of a function that calls both then and fail:

```
user.checkToken = function (token, db, callback) {
    if (token) {
        db.get('acces_tokens', token).then(function (res) {
            if (new Date(res.body.expire) > new Date()) {
                //Token is valid
                callback(res.body.user, res.body.expire);
            } else {
                //Token has expired
                callback(false, "Token has expired");
            }
        }).fail(function (err) {
            callback(false, "ERROR");
        });
    } else {
        callback(false, "A token is needed");
    }
};
```

I do not understand it :(

**EDIT**: It turn out it only does this when I call it from certain functions. This is even weirder.

**EDIT 2**: I've been doing some debuging. I console.logged the entire promise like this:

```
console.log(
    db.get('acces_tokens', token)
        .then(function (res) {
            if (new Date(res.body.expire) > new Date()) {
                //Token in valid
                callback(res.body.user, res.body.expire);
            } else {
                //Token has expired
                callback(false, "Token has expired");
            }
        }).fail(function (err) {
        callback(false, "ERROR");
        })
)
```

And I got this:

```
{ promise: [Circular],
  _isPromise: true,
  _successFn: null,
  _failFn: [Function],
  _scope: [Circular],
  _boundArgs: null,
  _hasContext: false,
  _nextContext: undefined,
  _currentContext: undefined }
```

As you can see _successFn is null. I guess this is the problem but I do not understand why it is null :(

Comment: Its just plain weird - in many implementations of Promises `.then` is called both for success and failure (jQuery for example) - but your use is inline with the docs.

Comment: Yes that was my first thought! I looked the documentation carefully and I think this is correct. I even tried to swap .then for .success but it didn’t do the trick :(

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/orchestrate-io/orchestrate.js/issues/52

Comment: It turns out I had an error with a subsequent promise. Once fixed this started working. Thought the problem now is solved, I do not understand why promises can affect each other.

Comment: Basically, putting `.fail` (which should be equivalent to `.then(null, function () { ... })`) means to handle any errors from all previous promise functions if they haven't been handled yet. jQuery doesn't really have "proper" promises, so to speak.

Comment: With the expression `myPromise.then(successHandler).fail(errorHandler)`; (1) that `successHandler` and `errorHandler` should both fire is entirely reasonable, given that `.then()` returns a new promise and its `successHandler` might itself return a rejected promise; (2) the expression is not an "entire promise" as such - it's a *promise chain*, with a starter promise (`myPromise`) and a second promise returned by `.then()`, which the chain ultimately returns.

Comment: This comment is totally _Irelevent_: [Promises/A+ Performance Hits You Should Be Aware Of](http://thanpol.as/javascript/promises-a-performance-hits-you-should-be-aware-of/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But sometimes it triggers both and I don't understand why.

Because in the pattern you used - shortened to `promise.then(callback).fail(callback)` - `callback` might be called twice. If `promise` succeeds, your first `callback` is called, but when that callback throws an exception then the promise returned by `promise.then(callback)` is rejected and will call the `fail` callback you attached to it.

You'll need to use something along the lines of `promise.then(callback, callback)` to prevent this from happening. See [When is .then(success, fail) considered an antipattern for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for more explanations.

Of course, it would be better if you'd screw callbacks alltogether and just return a promise from your `checkToken` function :-)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't completely understand how promises work. I'll use your recommendation and return a promise :)